# Make scheduler unit test C# .Net

Tags: c#, unit-testing, scheduler

I've been stuck for several days to write a unit test of my scheduler code with C# on .NET.

I've been trying but it gives me some error like this

> Failed Update Controller:
>
> System.InvalidOperationException: No database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A provider can be configured by overriding the 'DbContext.OnConfiguring' method or by using 'AddDbContext' on the application service provider. If 'AddDbContext' is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type accepts a DbContextOptions object in its constructor and passes it to the base constructor for DbContext.

Is it because my database is still empty?

If there is some hint, it would help me a lot.

Thanks!

Comment: *"I've been trying"* What have you been trying? Please post a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: If it involves a database -> it's no longer a **unit** test, but an integration test instead ...

Comment: @marc_s While I generally tend to agree that it's best to avoid databases in most automated tests, there's no universally agreed-upon definition of what a *unit test* is...

Comment: @MarkSeemann: I was under the impression, it's generally accepted that as soon as an external dependency (file system, database, network call) is involved, it's no longer a "proper" unit test - but an integration test instead

Comment: @marc_s I'm mostly in that camp as well, but you can find published authors that know what they're talking about who use different definitions. I'm sorry I'm being vague here, but the names and works currently escape me, but I've definitely come across such works from people I felt that I couldn't easily dismiss. They're typically more from the 'traditional testing community' rather than agile TDDers, which is also why I can't think of actual names ATM...

Comment: Is it possible to make a unit test about sendbulkemail when the sendbulkemail task do not being called in my main code

Comment: @megapangastuti post your code. The error has nothing to do with schedulers, it says you tried to use a misconfigured DbContext and even tells you how to configure it.

Comment: The actual database doesn't matter as far as this error is concerned. You could configure the DbContext to use an [in-memory provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/testing/testing-without-the-database#in-memory-provider) or use [SQLite in memory-only mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/testing/testing-without-the-database#sqlite-in-memory) to test your code without an actual database